# Why is this website still in beta mode?

Tags: discussion

Just curious, [Politics.StackExchange](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) is a couple of  years old, so why still in beta or that the name of the forum?

Can a moderator explain this to me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What KPIs should be increased and to what values, so that Politics become a full member of SE community?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2870/what-kpis-should-be-increased-and-to-what-values-so-that-politics-become-a-full)

Comment: I am more surprised that the SE Overlords have allowed it to continue to exist, I will be floored if they ever deem it graduated.

Answer (score 7):

The current de-facto criteria is ["When a site starts to consistently receive 10 questions/day, we’ll consider it for graduation"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/166789).

Thus far, the Politics site usually has about 6 to 8 questions/day on average, although it does hit 10 sometimes due to various political events which prompt a lot of questions.

Comment: He's also made late night comedy great again so I guess that's another positive.

Answer (score 3):

It's not attracting enough questions (or answers) to graduate to a full site yet - but it's quite close:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25906/politics