# Reasons to impeach Trump, how to ask the question properly

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Can anyone think of a way to ask for reasons why Trump should be impeached but by asking for it in a more politically correct and on topic sort of manner on SE Politics?

If that is too broad entirely to ever work here then how could someone ask a question to get back such answers but by asking it in a different and not so blunt way where it would not be closed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem with asking for reasons why Trump should be impeached is that it is completely opinion-based. And I do  not mean opinion-based *for us*. It is opinion-based for the congresspeople who make the decision to impeach or not impeach. The US constitution says that a president can be impeached for "high crimes and misdemeanors" and whatever that means is open to the interpretation of congress. Fact is, impeaching the president is a political decision, not a legal or ethical decision.

And besides, this would be a [list-based question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124450/what-is-the-definition-of-a-list-question), and these don't really work in the Stack Exchange system.

If you just want to collect a "list of things Trump did wrong" which you can then use to agitate against him, then you might want to look for a more discussion-oriented platform with a declared anti-Trump / pro-Democrat agenda.

Comment: Thanks Pillipp - I guess I was assuming it could be asked another way such as why would congress want to impeach Trump, or what's the significance of certain things Trump has said or did that would raise flags for impeachment, etc. I was hoping someone good with words (slicksters) could think of a way to word it differently, but if it's not possible in this case, then it's not.  Your answer is more clear to me in the answer portion of the answer so I accepted it.

Comment: @PresidentBernieSanders - It's perfectly reasonable to ask about the significance of certain things (Is this normal? Is this overtly criminal? Is this similar to anything that people have discussed impeaching for before?).  But there's no good way to ask or answer as to whether any specific thing is impeachable for the reasons Philipp states.

Answer (score 4):

#### Short answer: Probably not without picking a narrow topic and asking broadly.

As I've stated before on [other questions related to opinion](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3696/is-opinion-based-the-same-as-subjective), I believe that a question that can be responded to with fact or research based information is perfectly within the scope of the community.

#### Example

Can a sitting US President be impeached for perjury?

#### Explanation

This question can be answered with a fact based response, doesn't mention any particular person, and has a broader context than asking about a particular incident related to perjury.

Answer (score 4):

One potential correction is to ask about what *has* happened instead of what *might* happen.

Try:

> What reasons have U.S. congress-people mentioned for impeaching or not impeaching President Trump?

This is a straight-forward empirical question. It can be answered based on the public statements of a narrow set of governmental officials. It doesn't directly answer your question of why the President *should* be impeached, but we don't answer normative questions like that here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's impossible before a trial happened and we know the outcome. Any answer would rely on assumptions (if X happened then) or speculation (we can guess that X happened because ...).

If it were a simple case and the evidence were there then the impeachment process would already have started or the evidence supporting the process would have been put in the public domain (e.g. those with the evidence cannot start an impeachment procedure so they make it public to rally behind their cause).

Comment: But how could I word the question in a way so it'd be appropriate for the question in this SE community to get some of the reasons why this would/should be considered? Certainly there are legitimate and reasonable reasons why people think this should/shouldn't happen with as much you hear about it but as soon as you ask some sort of question like this, nothing but down votes or to get closed as you are scrutinizing, etc. Is it possible to word this sort of a question in a way to make it appropriate for this SE community and a good question?

Comment: @PresidentBernieSanders I think the question is better suited for a discussion forum or some site that seeks discussion and opinions. Simple rephrasing doesn't solve that problem. Why do you think the question is suited for this site (aimed at objective information and facts)?